# E-mail form validation - add "filter" to block certain words in the message field

Tags: forms, validation, email-validation

I have a online Contact Us form. Within the FormValidate.php file I have this string of code.
I need to BLOCK (error will show saying "invalid") the sending of the e-mail if specific words are typed into the message field.

This is what I have in the FormValidate.php

```
        $return_value = "";
        foreach($this->error_messages as $message) {
            $return_value .= "<li>$message</li>";
        }
        return $return_value;
    }
```

Or this...

```
<?php

class FormValidate {
    
    private $error_messages = array(); 
    private $lang;

    public function setLang($lang) {
        $this->lang = $lang;
    }
    
    public function validate($value, $field_rules) {

        $display_name = $field_rules['label'];

        // exclude if not required and no value passed
        if(!$field_rules['required'] && $this->isEmpty($value)) {
            return;
        }

        // check required and no value passed
        if($field_rules['required'] && $this->isEmpty($value)) {
            $this->error_messages[] = $this->createMessage($display_name, '', $this->lang->{'required'});
            return;
        }
```

I am not sure what and where to do it.
Thank you!